# How do I store result of a command in textfile?

Tags: 12.04

How do I save result of a command in a textfile?

Eg, storing result of dpkg --get-selctions in a file named packages.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use redirect >

For example: `dpkg --get-selections > pkg.list`